# Update inner object of mongo model with innder id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My Model which has coure_name, c_material as array, c_task as array and I am trying to fetch the results based on the below query:

```js
const taks_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    course_name : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique : [true,  "Someone register using this email"],
        trim : true
    },
    c_material : [
        {
            m_name : {
                type : String
            },
            m_link : {
                type : String
            },
            m_file : {
                type : String
            },
            m_date : {
                type : String
            }
        }
    ],
    c_task : [
        {
            t_name : {
                type : String
            },
            t_details : {
                type : String
            },
            t_start_date : {
                type : Date
            },
            t_end_date : {
                type : Date
            },
            t_q_file : {
                type : String
            },
            t_s_file : [
                {
                    t_s_email: {
                        type : String
                    },
                    t_s_file_inner : {
                        type : Array
                    },
                    t_s_file_Date : {
                        type : Date
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

I apply this query which searches through the database, but get 0 modified in the result object.

```
let submit_files = await stu_task.updateOne({$and: [{course_name : "Web Development with Node js"}, {c_task : {_id : req.body.task_id}}]}, {$set : {c_task : {t_s_file : {t_s_email : check_cookie.email, t_s_file_inner : files_names, t_s_file_Date : Date.now()}}}});
```

Is there any problem in the query that I have created?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "c_task._id" defined in the schema , but you have it in the updateOne search criteria ...

Comment: c_task._id automatically generated just assume id in under c_task and i get inner object id using req.body.task_id

Answer (score 0):

You also need arrayFilters to update nested arrays check the [documentation](https://thecodebarbarian.com/a-nodejs-perspective-on-mongodb-36-array-filters) and also you need a id to search in `t_s_file` array in following query is used `t_s_email` field because I don't know the real data, so I searching in `t_s_file` based on  `t_s_email` can using `_id` if exist

```
await stu_task.updateOne(
  {
    $and: [
      { course_name: "Web Development with Node js" },
      { "c_task._id": req.body.task_id },
    ],
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "c_task.$[].t_s_file.$[i].t_s_email": {
        t_s_email: check_cookie.email,
        t_s_file_inner: files_names,
        t_s_file_Date: Date.now(),
      },
    },
  },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "i.t_s_email": "email@gmail.com" }] }
);
```